# Отключить предупреждение о неиспользуемом результате

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, clion, warning

Доброго времени суток!

Разрабатываю программу в среде **CLion** на платформе **Ubuntu 12.04**.
**CMake** version: 3.6.3.
**GDB** version: 7.11.1.
При сборке проекта компилятор выдаёт warning:

> warning: ignoring return value of ‘int system(const char*)’, declared
>   with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]

С одной стороны, это полезное предупреждение на тот случай, если резальтат функции нигде не используется, но не тогда, когда эта функция - **system()**. Подскажите пожалуйста, как отключить это предупреждение, и возможно ли это сделать, если я использую параметр оптимизации -O3?

Вот что в файле **CMakeList.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(MyProj)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O3")
set(SOURCE_FILES Main.cpp)
set(HEADER_FILES Main.h)
add_executable(MyProj ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: Тот факт, что функция `system` объявлена в GCC с атрибутом `warn_unused_result` говорит о том, что авторы библиотеки считают наоборот: они считают, что *именно* для функции `system` стоит выдавать предупреждение о проигнорированном результате. Компиляторы  С обычно не выдают таких предупреждений, за исключением тех случаев, когда оно явно запрошено. Функция `system` - как раз такой случай. Если уж вам так не хочется проверять результат `system`, то я бы посоветовал вам не отключать его глобально, а просто явно в коде приводить результат вызова к типу `(void)` - это подавит предупреждение.

Comment: @AnT, спасибо за ответ! Как вариант: написал функцию-обёртку для system(), теперь внутри неё получаю error code, а во всех остальных местах вызываю обёртку.

Comment: Изменение `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O3")` на `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O3 -Wno-unused-result")` даёт ту же ошибку?